# Validate XML file with schxslt and xslt3 (saxon-js)

Tags: xslt, saxon-js

I am struggling to understand the steps to validate an XML file with schxslt-cli, xslt3, and saxon-js.
These are the files that i use:

- schxslt-cli.jar + stylesheet (https://github.com/schxslt/schxslt/releases/tag/v1.9.5)
- CEN-EN16931-UBL.sch (https://github.com/OpenPEPPOL/peppol-bis-invoice-3/blob/master/rules/sch/CEN-EN16931-UBL.sch)
- PEPPOL-EN16931-UBL.sch (https://github.com/OpenPEPPOL/peppol-bis-invoice-3/blob/master/rules/sch/PEPPOL-EN16931-UBL.sch)

Steps that i tried:

1. Compiled Stylesheet:
   `java -jar schxslt-cli.jar -s CEN-EN16931-UBL.sch -d schxslt/2.0/pipeline-for-svrl.xsl -o output.xsl`
   Not sure if the commands that i used are correct, because the resulting stylesheet is too simple
2. xslt3 -xsl:output.xsl -export:output.sef.json
   This gives error:

```
Error XTSE0150 on line 1 in Artifacts/output.xsl:
  Simplified stylesheet root element lacks @xsl:version
Failed to compile stylesheet
```

I am also not sure of what to do next, should I use SaxonJS.transform() on the SEF file?

Comment: As far as I understand it, schxslt-cli has all you need to perform Schematron validation with that tool. I don't understand at which stage you want to insert SaxonJS, an XSLT 3 processor, unless you don't want to use the cli version of Schxslt but just the stylesheets and run them with SaxonJS, then you would use e.g. `xslt3 -xsl:pipeline-for-svrl.xsl -s:CEN-EN16931-UBL.sch -o:CEN-EN16931-UBL.compiled.xsl` plus `xslt3 -xsl:CEN-EN16931-UBL.compiled.xsl -s:someInstanceDoc.xml`.

Comment: The `-d` argument for the Schxslt cli is the instance XML document you want to validate, the `-s` is the Schematron schema, e.g. in your case `-s:CEN-EN16931-UBL.sch`, the `-o` is the the `svrl` output report Schxslt generates when validating your instance against the Schematron schema. The compilation step is done under the hood.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to change my code for now

Comment: In terms of "precompiling" to SEF with and for SaxonJS/xslt3, you can of course do e.g. `xslt3 -t -nogo -xsl:pipeline-for-svrl.xsl -export:pipeline-for-svrl.xsl.sef.json -relocate:on` and then instead of `xslt3 -xsl:pipeline-for-svrl.xsl -s:CEN-EN16931-UBL.sch -o:CEN-EN16931-UBL.compiled.xsl` you would use e.g. `xslt3 -xsl:pipeline-for-svrl.xsl.sef.json -s:CEN-EN16931-UBL.sch -o:CEN-EN16931-UBL.compiled.xsl`.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to precompile to SEF so I can validate it using SaxonJS.transform() (Is it the correct API to use?). But I misunderstand after reading somewhere to use schxslt to precompile it

Comment: You should be able (in principle, I haven't tested it) to use schxslt on Java to generate a validation stylesheet, which you can then either run directly on NodeJS using the xslt3 command in SaxonJS, or cross-compile into a SEF file.

Comment: With XSLT based Schematron validation, you will use two XSLT stylesheets, first the Schxslt one to compile your Schematron schema to another XSLT, then that XSLT on the instance to perform the validation. Thus, for SaxonJS, if you have a fixed Schematron schema you can do the precompilation first for the Schxslt stylesheet(s), then use the resulting sef.json to compile the Schematron schema into an XSLT, again use `xslt3 -export` to precompile to sef.json, and that result can then in any validation you want to perform used with SaxonJS.transform against an XML input document.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael and Martin